# Branch cuts of the Hypergeometric function with one complex parameter

Tags: hypergeometric-function, branch-cuts

I am trying to understand if the hypergeometric function with the following choice of parameters has any branch cut in the complex plane
$$
\ _{2}F_{1}\left(a,b - i \rho ,c ,1-z^{2}\right)
$$

here $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\rho > 0$.

I did some numerical explorations with Mathematica and I was not able to find any branch cuts on the real line. Is this property true?

I was not able to find any reference on the branch cuts of the hypergeometric function with complex parameters.

Comment: sorry I am dumb, I was influenced by Mathematica where the imaginary unit $i$ is written as capital $I$.

Comment: The analytic continuation and branch points are understood from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type

Answer (score 1):

Complex parameters have nothing to do with the choice of branch cuts. The conventional way to fix the branch cut on the principal sheet of the Riemann surface of $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ is to draw it from $1$ to $+\infty$ along the real axis in the complex plane of $x$. For example, this is how $_2F_1$ is implemented in Mathematica.

In terms of your $z$-variable, this branch cut corresponds to two halves of the imaginary axis. Specifically, $z\mapsto 1-z^2$ maps each of the half planes $\Re z\gtrless0$ to $\mathbb C\backslash[1,+\infty)$. So the signature of the branch cut will be the difference  between the values of $_2F_1(1-z^2)$, calculated for $z=\pm i\alpha+0$ (or $z=i\alpha\pm 0$) for $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.